# Poisson distribution, the meaning of the parameter lambda

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution

What is the best intuition behind the unique parameter $\lambda$ in the Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poisson RV is commonly used for modelling number of occurrences of an event within a particular time interval. And, since $E[X]=\lambda$, its unique parameter is referred as *mean number of event occurrences* within our particular time interval.

Comment: That's nice. Can be something be added about the "particular time inetrval" ?

Comment: e.g. $X$: number of customers arriving daily; here time interval is day.

Comment: Is the Poisson distribution strictly speaking discrete or can it be even continuous ? I.e. can we say that there is a probability of number customers arrving daily 2.45 ?

Comment: Poisson is a discrete RV. It can be 0,1,2,...

Comment: Yes but it has continuous analog if we intersperse curve through the discrete values at $0,1,2,...$ Can this be done and understood formally?

Comment: First of all, you can do that with a suitable choice of normalizing constant. But, this is a very different question, which I'm hesitant to answer here. You should ask it in a different thread for someone to provide some intuition to this continuous version.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Poisson distribution is defined as

> $$\pi_{\lambda}(k)~=~\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$

It is not hard to show that $E[X]=\lambda$ and $D^2[X]=\lambda$. Therefore you can directly interpret $\lambda$ as the expectation or as well as the variance of the poisson distributed variable.