# Continuous analog of the Poisson R.V.

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I was suggested [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964448/poisson-distribution-the-meaning-of-the-parameter-lambda) to ask if the Poisson R.V. can have the continuous analog, namely if it makes sense that the non-integrality of the parameter $\lambda$ and/or interlaced curve at the discrete values of the Poisson distribution can be handled formally.

Comment: The Poisson distribution makes sense for any positive real $\lambda$ not just integers, and in fact it would be quite unnatural for $\lambda$ to be required to take discrete values. The fact that the parameter is continuous has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that the Poisson distribution is discrete (i.e. a poisson random variable takes only natural number values.)

Comment: And it doesn't really make sense to consider a continuous version of the Poisson distribution. The whole point of the Poisson is it is a distribution of number of events that occur in some interval. (If you want to 'just force it' there's also the minor question of how to interpolate the factorial that occurs in the distribution. Could use gamma function, but what's the motivation?). When $\lambda$ gets big, then many different event counts become likely, and the distribution starts to look continuous and be well-approximated by a normal in a sense.

Comment: Aren't these two sentences in contradiction:The Poisson distribution makes sense for any positive real λ not just integers.//Poisson distribution is discrete (i.e. a poisson random variable takes only natural number values.) ??This is actually where was my problem but after your comment it still remained unsolved.

Comment: No, $\lambda$ is a *parameter*... In this case is happens to correspond to the average value. Something can have an average value of $13.27$ and still only be able to take integer values. As a simpler case take a Bernoulli distribution, where the variable takes the value $1$ with probability $p$ and zero otherwise. Doesn’t get much more discrete than that, but the *parameter* $p$ can be anything between zero and one.